# MIPS Minimum Needed Memory Space

Tags: mips

What is the minimum amount of memory required to run the program whose portion is presented below and which runtime on a MIPS of 5 pipeline stages, 2 nanoseconds per stage for fixed-point operations? In floating point operations stage EX costs 16 ns. The instructions only last quantities of pipeline stages required for its execution (assume that there is no conflict of pipeline).

```
.data
    Pf1:    .word 0x41400000
    Vet1:   .double 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0

.text

leaf_example:
    addi $sp, $sp, -48
    sw $s0, 0($sp)
    sll $t0, $s0, 5
label:  addu $t0, $t0, $s2
    sll $t0, $t0, 3
    addu $t0, $a1, $t0
    bgt $t0, $s0, label
    l.d $f18, 0($t0)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the pipelining and time spent on particular stages helps the dynamic instruction count and/or instruction processing time, but not the memory that is required to store the program.

`.text` starts at 0x10010000

`.data` starts at 0x00400000

It seems reasonable that how much memory you need depends on if the hardware/chipset can virtually present memory at different locations without needing physical memory to fill the gaps.

## No Virtual/Logical Memory Management

If there was no chipset or system providing logical memory management, it seems that you would need 4194304 bytes, or 4 MB if you didn't have a `.data` section. If you have anything in `.data`, then it would need to be at least 256MB + 64 KB + however many bytes you're storing.

In your example, this would mean that you need 256 MB + 64 KB + 36 bytes = 268501028 bytes, or about 256.07 MB.

## With Virtual Memory Management

Suppose your MIPS program is running on a platform that is doing virtual memory management. Then the system could present memory at location 0x10010000, for example, without actually having all of the previous addresses (like 0x1000ffff) physically located.

Also, this analysis could work if you use a modified MIPS memory layout. In MARS, you can compact the memory by setting `.data` to start at address 0x0.

Here it would be a straightforward calculation of the instructions plus the data. In your example, since `ble` and `l.d` are pseudo-instructions, they increase the number of instructions from the apparent 8 to 11 real machine instructions. 11 words in `.text` (44 bytes) plus 9 words in `.data` (36 bytes) gives 80 bytes.